# Does nginx cache my responses?

Tags: symfony, nginx, symfony-2.1

I'm using Symfony2 with nginx as http server (I don't know much about reverse proxies, I just installed it and didn't touch anything), without Apache nor Varnish.

I need to know whether nginx is caching the responses I send with the correct headers, like public, max-age, and s-max-age, or I have to add something else to the stack, like Varnish.

I have read somewhere that if you add Varnish, you will have to add yet something else, for gzip compression. So it would be nginx -> Varnish -> ???

So is nginx caching? How can I check that? I did `grep cache` on the nginx logs and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use nginx caching you should configure it.

- http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_cache_path
- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_path

[You do not need Varnish unless ESI is required.](http://todsul.com/nginx-varnish)